# Expected value of Poisson pdf $p(a\mid X)$, where $X$ is also Poisson distributed

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I had a hard time figuring out how to phrase this question, so please forgive the confusing title.

To be concrete: the expected value of a function $g(X)$ of a random variable $X$, where $X$ has the pdf $f(x)$, can be computed as:

$$ E[g(X)] = \int_R \! g(x) f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Now in my case, I have

$$ f(x) = \mathrm{Poisson}(x\mid\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}{e^{-\lambda}} $$

and $g(x)$ is also Poisson, except its mean is $X$, so we have

$$ g(x) = \mathrm{Poisson}(a\mid x) = \frac{x^a}{a!}{e^{-x}} $$

and what I want is the integral

$$ E[\mathrm{Poisson}(a\mid X)] = \int_R \!  \mathrm{Poisson}(a\mid x) \mathrm{Poisson} (x\mid\lambda) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
 = \int_0^\infty \! \frac{x^a}{a!}{e^{-x}} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}{e^{-\lambda}} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

or the discrete version is fine as well:

$$ E[\mathrm{Poisson}(a\mid X)] = \sum_x \frac{x^a}{a!}{e^{-x}} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}{e^{-\lambda}} $$

Do either of these have an analytic solution? What if $$ \mathrm{Poisson}(a\mid x) $$ was approximated by a normal distribution?

Physically this situation arises when e.g. a Poisson process produces some random number of particles, which then go on to trigger another cascade of particles, and we are interested in the pdf of the number of particles in the second cascade. So we sum over all the possible numbers of particles coming from the first process. This is straightforward to do numerically, but I just wonder if there isn't a way to do it analytically... I tried to compute it via characteristic functions but that just made it worse I think:

$$ E[\mathrm{Poisson}(a\mid X)] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{a!}\Gamma(a+1) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (1-i \omega)^{-a-1}\cdot e^{\lambda\left(e^{i \omega} - 1 \right)} \, \mathrm{d} \omega$$

(assuming I didn't screw up getting that far)

Comment: Are you saying: Draw $X$ from a $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, and then draw $Y$ from a $\text{Poisson}(X)$, what is the unconditional distribution of $Y$?

Comment: Yes, that's it :)

Comment: Just a small question, it seems to me that the physical model you are describing leads to a distribution which is slightly different from your proposal. Indeed, let $N, X_1, X_2, X_3, \cdots$ be i.i.d $\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ describing the cascade of each particle. Then the second cascade can be written as the random sum $$Y = \sum_{k=1}^{N} X_k, $$ where $N$ is interpreted as the first cascade and $X_k$ are interpreted as the contribution of the $k$-th particle in the second cascade. Simplifying, we have $Y \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda N)$. It seems we need extra $\lambda$ factor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the expectation rather than the distribution, then you can use the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

$$\mathbb{E}[a] = \mathbb{E}_X\left[\mathbb{E}_{a \mid X}[a \mid X]\right]$$
and in this example this is 
$$ =  \mathbb{E}_X\left[X\right] = \lambda$$

If you want further evidence, you could try simulation.  For example in R,

```
set.seed(1)
cases <- 1000000
lambda <- 7
X <- rpois(cases, lambda)
a <- rpois(cases, X)
```

gives

```
> mean(X)
[1] 6.998076
> mean(a)
[1] 6.999449
```

with the final result closer to $\lambda$ than it deserves to be

Answer (score 0):

The Poisson distribution is a discrete distribution.  Its support is the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  If $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda),$ then
$$
\operatorname{E}(g(X)) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty g(x) \frac{e^{-\lambda} x^\lambda}{x!}.
$$
(Be careful about when I use capital $X$ and when I use lower-case $x$.)

Comment: Sure, sure, but in my question I am happy to use the continuous generalisation, so if that helps to solve the integral/sum then that's fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

$$X\sim\text{Po}(\lambda), Y\mid X\sim\text{Po}(X)\implies\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\sum_x \mathbb{P}(Y=y\mid X=x)\mathbb{P}(X=x)$$

$$\implies\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\sum_x \frac{x^y e^{-x}}{y!}\frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{y!}\sum_{x\ge0}\frac{x^y\left(\lambda e^{-1}\right)^x}{x!}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{y!} T_y(\lambda e^{-1})$$

where $T_y$ are [Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials) - I'm not sure these simplify much more in the general case.